# cakePHP Flash message append class not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to get my head around the flash message functionality in cakePHP.

In my current script is use the following approach:

```
     $this->Session->setFlash('Error');
```

which as a result gives me the following output:

```
    <div id="flashMessage" class="message">Error</div>
```

However when I try to append a custom class to it:

```
    $this->Session->setFlash('Error', array ('class' => 'errormsg'));
```

the message / flash does not seem to be generated / is not visible in my sourcecode output at all.

Any ideas what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try changing:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Error', array ('class' => 'errormsg'));
```

to

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Error', 'default', array ('class' => 'errormsg'));
```

See:: cakePHP [setFlash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent::setFlash)

Answer (score 3):

As per cakephp session component you have to pass like below

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Error', 'default', array('class' => 'errormsg'));
```

you can take more reference from [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent%3a%3asetFlash)

let me know if i can help you

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful information - appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For those using Cake 2.7+ ([where `SessionComponent::setFlash` is deprecated](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent::setFlash)), use

```
$this->Flash->set('Error', array('params' => array('class' => 'errormsg')));
```